# Merging folders in different repositories

Tags: git, git-merge, git-bash

*Hello i have searched around for an answer but couldn't quite find what i was looking for, feel free to link in the comments if i missed an answer somewhere.*

I cloned two repositories down on my pc.

**Repository 1:** A collection of different components, one of which i have worked on and made changes to.

**Repository 2:** The updated version of the component i was working on, this has the changes from other people, but does not have my changes.

I guess i wouldn't be able to merge my repository 1 with repository 2 because of all the other components present in my repository, is there a way i can just merge a single folder containing files, with the same folder in repository 2?

Comment: Git only stores and works with *files*, not folders. Git will create folders as needed for your OS (because your OS probably doesn't consider `path/to/file` a file name, but rather a folder named `path` holding a folder named `to` holding a file named `file`, but for Git this is just a file named `path/to/file`). In any case, `git merge` works on a per-commit basis, not a per-file basis (though once you're past the commit selection, *then* the merge handles files: but it does all of them).

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to your question,

1. Enter the repository which has all your changes (this does not have the updated changes present in the server)
2. Do a `git pull --rebase`
3. Solve any merge conflicts.

Assuming that you have others changes synced to remote, and you have the correct remote URL set, in usual cases, you may choose to ignore this.